# Can I import javascript from outside of my managed package into a LWC in my package?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, managed-package, static-resources

In our managed package, we have a particular page where we have some default javascript that runs some calculations on some fields as you type and I am in the process of converting this page to LWCs.

The particular issue I have is that some of our clients require slightly different calculations to be run. I would like to upload these as functions in a javascript file inside a static resource in their org, but I need to be able to reference this from inside out managed package. Is this even possible? I'm struggling to find a way.

It doesn't have to be a static resource - it could be a LWC with no UI (just a javascript file).

Either way, the problem seems to be adding javascript from outside of the managed package into a component that is inside of the package.

Any thoughts would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Andy

Comment: I'm about 90% sure that the answer to this is "not in LWC." You may have an easier time of it in Aura, though.

Answer (score 2):

Ok - I came up with a solution. It's not the best because it uses `eval` but since all we will be doing are some simple calculations on object fields and then returning the object, I think it's fine.

In my apex controller, I simply query for the static resource (Id and Body) with a specific name - this will return a static resource, regardless of whether it originated outside of our managed package or not, and the javascript content as a string in from the Body field. If something is returned, I simply `eval` it which gives me a function to call on my object.

I've tested it and it works perfectly.